# ruby prevent division by zero

Tags: ruby, divide-by-zero

In some cases such expression

```
...some loop
  solution = n[0].to_s+a[0]+n[1].to_s+a[1]+n[2].to_s+a[2]+n[3].to_s+a[3]+n[4].to_s+a[4]+n[5].to_s 
  puts solution if eval(solution) == 100

#=> `eval': divided by 0 (ZeroDivisionError)
```

how to prevent this situation or, maybe, skip loop calculation and continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you really just want to skip the current calculation and step forward, the simplest way would be a begin-rescue statement

```
loop do
  begin
    solution = n[0].to_s+a[0]+n[1].to_s+a[1]+n[2].to_s+a[2]+n[3].to_s+a[3]+n[4].to_s+a[4]+n[5].to_s
    puts solution if eval(solution) == 100
  rescue ZeroDivisionError
    # catch error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoa. I suspect:

```
n[0].to_s+a[0]+n[1].to_s+a[1]+n[2].to_s+a[2]+n[3].to_s+a[3]+n[4].to_s+a[4]+n[5].to_s
```

AKA:

```
n[0].to_s +
a[0] +
n[1].to_s +
a[1] +
n[2].to_s +
a[2] +
n[3].to_s +
a[3] +
n[4].to_s +
a[4] +
n[5].to_s
```

could be better written as:

```
n[0..5].map(&:to_s).zip(a[0..4]).flatten.join
```

or:

```
n.map(&:to_s).zip(a).flatten.join
```